# Angular2 displaying a particular Questions from the JSON for the selected dropdown values after finding a proper match

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material2

I have a dropdown which has numeric values like 1 and 2. In my JSON, I have a `"filters"` attribute which is an array. The requirement is:

Whenever I select any value from the dropdown — let's say I have selected 2 in the dropdown — then I want to check if the selected value is equal to any of the "answer" attribute in the "filters" array whose value is same as the selected value, i.e 2.

If more than one object has the same answer value, it should check if the `"code"` matches the "questionCode" of "filters` array for the selected match. If yes, then the respective "displayKey" should be displayed.

My JSON:

```
{
     "code": "abc",
     "displayKey": "question1",
     "filters": [{
     "questionCode": "abc",
     "answer": "2"
           }],
     "order": 9,
     "industryList": {}
}, 
{
    "code": "pqr23",
    "displayKey": "question2",
    "filters": [{
        "questionCode": "gthy67",
        "answer": "1"
               }],
    "order": 2,
    "industryList": {}
},
{
    "code": "abc",
    "displayKey": "question3",
    "filters": [{
    "questionCode": "abc342",
    "answer": "2"
          }],
    "order": 9,
    "industryList": {}
}
```

In my .ts file:

```
 for(var i=0; i<=this.questions.filters.length;i++ ){
       var questionsObj = this.questions.filters[i];
       //psuedoCode
       if(this.selectedValue == questionsObj.answer){
         if(this.questions.code == questionsObj.questionCode ){
           this.displayFilterCode = true;
         }  
         else{
          this.displayFilterCode = false;
        }       
       }       
     }
```

My JSON is very big and i am saving the entire object in a `questions` object. I have just added the required bit here.

In my HTML:

```
<dropdown [(ngModel)] = "selectedValue"></dropdown>
```

My dropdown is populating properly on the page but not sure why the respective questions are not being displayed. Can anyone let me know what I am doing wrong and how can I get the questions displayed. I am not sure if I am following the right approach but I am trying out this way. Also, I am getting error as length undefined (not sure why). Since `filters` is an array so `filters.length` should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well you are not accessing your json properly.
this is what you should try

```
for(var i=0; i<=this.questions.length;i++ ){
       var questionsObj = this.questions[i];
       //now one question from question array is assigned to questionobj
       if(this.selectedValue == questionsObj.filters[0].answer){// your answer is in questionsObj.filters[0].answer position
         if(this.questions[i].filters[0].questionCode == questionsObj.filters[0].questionCode ){
           this.displayFilterCode = true;
         }  
         else{
          this.displayFilterCode = false;
        }       
       }
```

let me know if you still face any error. because i don't know from where you are getting this.seletedValue.

Comment: I was using .length in my for loop but I was getting error saying length is undefined.

Comment: @techiequestie your .length will not work. for that length you have to for loop questions array which is also an array of object.

Comment: I think we need to have one more for loop to iterate over filters array. Can you confirm?

Comment: @techiequestie there is only object in filters array. if you have multiple objects in your filters array then you can use one more for loop using any of `questionsObj.filters.length`  or  `this.questions[i].filters.length` for filter array elements

Comment: that for loop thing was  a good catch but it is still not working.Trying to debug.I will get back to you.

Comment: I am using this.selectedValue to compare the selected dropdown value with the answer attribute in JSON. I am using selectedValue in ngModel to get that.But thats not able to map. Any clue what I am doing wrong.

Comment: @techiequestie hmm how you are assigning value in selectedValue using ngModel. i use ngModel in form tag only. show some html part code if possible. i would use selectedValue some different way. like this `<dropdown  (click)="onSelect(data)"> {{data.value}} </dropdown>` and in js   `onSelect(selected: any): void { this.selectedValue = selected;  }`